# ngSubmit "myFunction is not a function" typescript, angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an address management app, and I'm trying to save changes on ngSubmit. However, it says that my function is not a function.
my HTML:

```
<div class="form">
  <h4>{{title}}</h4>
  <div class="form-container">
   <form (ngSubmit)="addFriend()">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id">Id</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" [(ngModel)]="friend.id"
        [disabled]="friend.id" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="friend.name"
                            class="form-control" required />
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" [(ngModel)]="friend.address"
                            class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" [(ngModel)]="friend.phone"
                            class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <a class="btn btn-default" routerLink="">Cancel</a>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" >Save</button>
  </div>

  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

am I doing something wrong in the html, or would the problem be elsewhere?

The addFriend function is defined in my service.ts file.

Comment: You should add your ts file for us to understand what you did wrong :)

Comment: Ok, so guys on the bottom were right, but now I understand why. I had defined that function in my service.ts, but I was calling it from component, where it wasn't. issue resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define `addFriend` in your component ts file like

```
addFriend(){
//some work here
}
```

Comment: checked for specifying that component.ts file.

Answer (score 1):

Your component template does not have access to your service, but only to your component class methods.

So you need to
1/ inject your service into your component
2/ define in your component a method that calls the service methods

for example in your component :

```
constructor(private friendsService: FriendsService) {}
....
addFriend(){
    return this.friendsService.addFriend();
}
```

Comment: it should goes to comments or should have some description